# how to disable past date in calendar extendar in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to know how to **disable** pasts date in calendar extender in **asp.net** Code behind. I want to do it code behind without using **java scripts**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the  `StartDate` property:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      CalendarExtender1.StartDate = DateTime.Today;
}
```

http://www.advancesharp.com/blog/1002/disable-dates-in-ajax-calendarextender

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this on page load:

```
Calendar1.StartDate = DateTime.Now;
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was a matter of search far from your end. Anyways here is the total solution

**ASPX**

```
<asp:CalendarExtenderID="Calendar1"runat="server" 
Enabled="True" TargetControlID="TextBox1"Format="dd/MM/yyyy" ></asp:CalendarExtender>
```

**CS**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Calendar1.StartDate = DateTime.Now;   //to disable past Date
}
```

Documentation on Datetime:- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx

Hope that helps you